# Open Stack Installation On Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, openstack

Can any one provide step by step installation of Open stack installation on Ubuntu 14.04?

**Or**

Is there any script like http://openstack.redhat.com/Quickstart for auto installation. I have tried devstack on Ubuntu but it didn't work ( Credentials Not Working ).

[Dumidu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/465863/169736) did work (Installation) but there is no username or password for the installation, so there is nothing to check its working or not.

Is there any way to install Openstack on Ubuntu?

Comment: Admin password is not working... @Braiam

Comment: @Braiam I am trying to install open stack in VM

Comment: step by step installation @Jobin

Comment: You need the step-by-step installation for the devstack installation or the manual one?

Comment: manual one and with a little bit detail.... @Jobin

Comment: is it fine now ? @Jobin

Comment: To know how things work in open stack @Jobin

Comment: This is for test env @Jobin after that production

Comment: Have you tried one of the Ubuntu Defaults for OpenStack? They put out Ubuntu Cloud, which seems like it'd be what you're looking for. Resources
--------- [Ubuntu Cloud Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure) [Ubuntu Cloud](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud) [Ubuntu Cloud Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud)

Comment: I know that and i have 10's of links in my bookmarks ... i Need steps or some script that do installation.

Comment: Our docs are out of date on this, but for people who want to dig in this is the place to start: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/OpenStackCharms

Comment: have you tried the steps in the order documented[here](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/ubuntu-openstack)?

Comment: @JorgeCastro Thanks , @E Carter Young yes i tried that Mass > juju after that juju was not connecting to mass, they were on the same server, You see redhat got one script you have nothing to do with ...just run the script and kaboom here you go, But only thing i want is to install it on Ubuntu. I hope you guys get my point that i didn't know much about openstack and juju so that is why i am asking the steps or auto installation

Comment: @Jobin yes it will .......

Comment: Did you read http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/install-guide/install/apt/content/index.html?

Comment: Go through this link https://gist.github.com/kordless/4042624  This link will show for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but it also works for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 7):

You can use devstack to deploy openstack on your machine. devstack is used for development and is probably the fastest and easiest way to deploy openstack. We first setup the environment to deploy openstack and then install openstack using devstack.

### Preparing the environment:

1. Deploy a virtual machine with ubuntu 14.04 as the guest OS on your ubuntu 14.04. You can use various hypervisors for deploying the virtual machine, I have used VMware Player. For instructions on how to deploy a virtual machine using VMware Player, refer to this tutorial:

   - [VMware Player- Installing and deploying virtual machines on ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player)
2. Next, after you have deployed the virtual machine and it is ready to use, you need to clone the devstack script from the github repositories, so first install git using the terminal(press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> together) and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git
   ```

   and enter your password and wait for the installation to complete. Now get the devstack script using the command below:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git
   ```

   This will take sometime depending upon your connection speed.

### Installing openstack:

1. If the script and other files downloaded successfully, you will get a directory `devstack` in the folder you executed this command. Go into the directory and type:

   ```
   cd devstack
   ```

   and then execute the script that fetches and install packages required by openstack using:

   ```
   ./stack.sh
   ```
2. You will be asked to set the password for administration and a few packages like mysql, rabbitmq, etc(six times in all); you could keep the passwords short and simple and may be even same if you don't wish to remember a different one for all. This will take roughly 2 hours to complete, again depending upon your connection speed (I assume it is around 200kbps). You can read about the script [here](http://devstack.org/stack.sh.html). The script will download and install and start various services and packages.
3. The output of the execution explains what scripts are being downloaded and other installation output; this will be useful to troubleshoot if you end up with an unsuccessful installation. If the script completes execution successfully, you will the output ending with the following lines:

   ```
   Horizon is now available at http://10.1.119.60/
   Keystone is serving at http://10.1.119.60:5000/v2.0/
   Examples on using novaclient command line is in exercise.sh
   The default users are: admin and demo
   The password: password
   This is your host ip: 10.1.119.60
   stack.sh completed in 257 seconds.
   ```

   If you don't get this, the script encountered some errors and they need to be sorted out first.*
4. If the installation is successful, you can open a browser and type the URL as given in the output message:

   `This is your host ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

   as shown above. **
5. You will get a page asking you the username and password. The username is `admin` and the password is what you entered when you installed openstack(the first of the six passwords). If you don't remember, open your `localrc` file in your devstack folder and check (It either be named `localrc`, or `.localrc` or `local.conf`).
6. If you ever happen to restart your machine or the virtual machine or even log off, you may need to restart openstack services since all of them are not started when the machine is booted. To restart the services, executed the following command on a terminal when you are in the `devstack` folder:

   ```
   ./rejoin-stack.sh
   ```

   and if completed successfully, all openstack services will be started and you should be able to access using the same username and password.
7. The installation above does not install neutron(the networking component), to install neutron, add the following to the end of your `localrc` file:

   ```
   disable_service n-net
   enable_service q-svc
   enable_service q-agt
   enable_service q-dhcp
   enable_service q-l3
   enable_service q-meta
   enable_service neutron
   #Optional, to enable tempest configuration as part of devstack
   enable_service tempest
   ```

   and then again execute `./stack.sh`.

**Notes:**

- Though you can install openstack on a bare-machine(not a virtual machine), it is recommended to install it on a virtual machine for security and for ease of use. The devstack installation removes your administrative password(rather does not ask for a password even for privileged commands). Also, you can create clones of your installtion and then even if you mess up your installation, you can discard the messed up one and then revert back to the latest working image of the virtual machine.
- It is better to install openstack on a new, clean virtual machine having an LTS OS on it, since support and testing is usually done on LTS, you will find more response on channels and forums if it is on an LTS version. Also the new virtual machine ensures there are no package version conflicts and helps in easing out the installation.
- If you are behind a proxy, you may need to add them in the virtual machine as environment variables in your `/etc/environment` file if you want to add it globally or in your `~/.bashrc` file if you want it locally and also in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. You may also need to tweak the script a little if git is not able to fetch packages even after adding http and https proxies.

<sub>*It is difficult to give a canonical solution to all those errors since a lot of ground needs to be covered and is nearly impossible to state them in one solution. After you have resolved the error that caused the script to fail, you need to restart the script using `./stack.sh` when you are in `devstack` folder.</sub>

<sub>**The reason you were getting the error when you logged in was because the installation was not successful or because you restarted, you need to restart openstack services if you restarted, if the installation failed, you need to troubleshoot the errors first and then restart the script.</sub>

Comment: @Qasim: Does this help install openstack?

Comment: @no not working ....nothing work.

Comment: @Qasim: Did you install a virtual machine successfully? Were the devstack scripts downloaded completely? What was the output of `./stack.sh`?

Comment: yes it run and installation went successfully, but nothing happen.

Comment: @Qasim: Did you get the final output as shown in the answer? If yes, what do you get when you type in your username and password in the login page on the browser when you type in the URL as the IP address?

Comment: You didn't get my point, Installation went fine, but there is no openstack installed...nothing is working

Comment: @Qasim: Can you please let me know what do you get when you execute ./rejoin-stack.sh when you are in devstack folder? Even you get an error message, paste it here or at pastebin.ubuntu.com and post the link here. It is difficult to make what you mean when you say "nothing is working" when I know this does install openstack.

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git -b stable/icehouse` when i use this comment i am getting an error as `fatal: Remote branch stable/icehouse not found in upstream origin
Unexpected end of command stream
` whats the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, I never try it but see if this work for you

```
# apt-get install python-software-properties
# add-apt-repository cloud-archive:icehouse
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-saucy linux-headers-generic-lts-saucy
# reboot
```

Reference: http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/install-guide/install/apt/content/basics-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

At present Devstack/Havana release supports only till ubuntu 12.04. You may try to install it in 14.04 however there might be issues in that. Please read devstack's Select a Linux Distribution here www.devstack.org