# Error in devstack installing on ubuntu

Tags: proxy, openstack

I'm getting following error while installing devstack on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
ERROR: openstack Error finding address for http://10.16.37.215:9292/v1/images: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

where 10.16.37.215 is my static IP address.

I was following the thread [Open Stack Installation On Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459590/open-stack-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04/468134#468134) to install devstack...

I'm guessing this problem is because I'm behind a proxy. But how to solve this problem? http_proxy/s is set everywhere in my system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to set:

```
no_proxy=10.16.37.215
```

this should help

Comment: Where does one need to set that and to what purpose?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Parto this actually is an answer - if a very short one without any explanation.