# Ubuntu Server 14.04 OpenStack Pre-Installed

Tags: 14.04, server, openstack

Hello the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes) for Ubuntu server 14.04 say that:

*"Ubuntu 14.04 LTS includes the OpenStack 2014.1 (Icehouse) release of the following projects in Ubuntu main*"

I installed the server but can't seem to find OpenStack. Do I have to install OpenStack on Ubuntu Server 14.04 separately using "apt" OR it is already installed and I just have to "[enable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627456/openstack-installation-on-ubuntu-server-14-04)" it?

EDIT:
Just a followup I also tried Ubuntu 15.04 (both desktop & server) but there also there is no openstack.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, it will not be part of the distribution. You need to install it. You can follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459590/open-stack-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04) and install openstack.